# Java/Intellij-Idea issues regarding brackets

Tags: java

It wants me to add a `" '(' or '[' "` but whatever I do It does not compile.

[image]

Comment: Add a `(` and a `)`.

Comment: Thank you for your response, could you please clarify @DawoodibnKareem?

Comment: I think your biggest issue is that you're trying to do four different things in one line of code.  Please don't do that.  Your code is far more readable if each operation has its own line.

Comment: `Map.put()` doesn't return `Map`.

Comment: That's true.  And it will become a non-issue if OP follows my advice and breaks this into 4 or 5 separate lines.

Comment: Thank you everyone I was meant to close this a while ago @DawoodibnKareem had the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you everybody for your contribution. @Dawood ibn Kareem had the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Add another opening parentheses `(` when creating the hashmap. You are calling the constructor with empty parameters of `HashMap` here. So,

```
...new HashMap<String, Double>()...
```

And you are missing another closing parentheses `)` at the end. As you are passing a `String` and a `Boolean`, the second generic type of the `HashMap` should be `Boolean` not `Double`.

```
...new HashMap<String, Boolean>()...
```

---

```
dataResult.add((new HashMap<String, Boolean>().put("i =", Boolean.parseBoolean(lines.get(i)))));
```

Remember this will change the return type of `put()` to `Boolean`.